# Formatting as a table in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get my head in the Scala game, and would welcome feedback on the following code, which produces a table from data.

```
class TabulatorTest extends FunSuite with ShouldMatchers {

  test("format") {
    Tabulator.format(List(
      List("head1", "head2", "head3"),
      List("one", "two", "three"), 
      List("four", "five", "six"))) should be ("""
+-----+-----+-----+
|head1|head2|head3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  one|  two|three|
| four| five|  six|
+-----+-----+-----+
""".trim)
  }

  test("format empty") {
    Tabulator.format(List()) should be ("")
    Tabulator.format(List(List())) should be ("""
++
||
++
++
""".trim)
  }

  test("uneven rows") {
    try {
      Tabulator.format(List(    
        List("head1", "head2", "head3"),
        List("one", "two")))
      fail()
    } catch {
      case e: IllegalArgumentException => 
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
object Tabulator {

  def format(table: Seq[Seq[Any]]) = table match {
    case Seq() => ""
    case _ => 
      val cellSizes = for (row <- table) yield 
        (for (cell <- row) yield 
          if (cell == null) 0 else cell.toString.length)
      val colSizes = for (col <- cellSizes.transpose) yield col.max
      val rows = for (row <- table) yield formatRow(row, colSizes)
      formatRows(rowSeparator(colSizes), rows)
  }

  def formatRow(row: Seq[Any], colSizes: Seq[Int]) = {
    val cells = (for ((item, size) <- row.zip(colSizes)) yield 
      if (size == 0) "" else ("%" + size + "s").format(item))
    cells.mkString("|", "|", "|")
  }

  def formatRows(rowSeparator: String, rows: Seq[String]): String = (
    rowSeparator :: 
    rows.head :: 
    rowSeparator :: 
    rows.tail.toList ::: 
    rowSeparator :: 
    List()).mkString("\n")


  private def rowSeparator(colSizes: Seq[Int]) =
    colSizes map { "-" * _ } mkString("+", "+", "+")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't help a lot. Only some syntactic hints:

```
object Tabulator {

  def format(table: Seq[Seq[Any]]) =
    if (table.isEmpty) ""
    else {
      def cellSize(cell: Any) =
        cell.toString.length

      val cellSizes =
        table map { _ map cellSize }
      val colSizes =
        cellSizes.transpose map { _.max }
      val rows =
        table map formatRow(colSizes)

      formatRows(rowSeparator(colSizes), rows)
    }

  def formatRow(colSizes: Seq[Int])(row: Seq[Any]) = {
    val cells =
      for ((item, size) <- row zip colSizes) yield
        if (size == 0) "" else "%"+size+"s" format item
    cells mkString ("|", "|", "|")
  }

  def formatRows(rowSeparator: String, rows: Seq[String]): String = (
       rowSeparator
    :: rows.head
    :: rowSeparator
    :: rows.tail.toList
    ::: rowSeparator
    :: Nil
  ) mkString "\n"


  private def rowSeparator(colSizes: Seq[Int]) =
    colSizes map { "-"*_ } mkString ("+", "+", "+")
}
```

I deleted the null-check in cellSize because `null` is not familiar in Scala. If you definitely need `null` then restore the check.

Comment: This is not `null` safe. You shoudl fix `cellSize` to use `Option(cell) map (_.toString.length) getOrElse 0`.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: I know that it is not null safe. But in Scala typically nobody uses null. And because I don't know what data the code has to handle I deleted the null-check. There can be null but maybe null is handled before the Tabulator is used? To your second comment: There is formatRow and formatRow **s**

Comment: Should I favour `if` over `case` for simple tests? I rather like the shape of the case rather than the annoying brackets and braces in if statements, and the case gives a nicer sense of different function bodies for different arguments like Lisp and Haskell.

Comment: @Antoras - it turns out that the Java objects that this is used to display often have null fields.

Comment: @Antoras - why define `cellSize` as a nested function, but have others as methods? Aren't I just loosing a place I could customise through subclassing?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - what does `Option(cell) map (_.toString.length) getOrElse 0` buy me that `if (cell == null) 0 else cell.toString.length` doesn't (apart from an extra object creation and method call ;-)?

Comment: @Antoras Oh, sorry, I didn't notice the distinction. I'd rename formatRow to formatCols. Easier on the eye. I'll remove the second comment, but I still think the first is relevant.

Comment: @Duncan The short answer is composability, though, perhaps, a better answer would be "mindset". The best practice in Scala is to wrap any null-returning API in conversions T => Option[T], for all nullable T. You can then rely on Scala to keep your code correct with respect to optional values.

Comment: @Daniel - so I should default to `Option(x)` and replace with `if (x == null)` only as an optimisation...

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor: If prefer if-else over match-case when there are only two cases and there are no data to extract. But that's only my own preference.

Comment: @Antoras - I must get used to Nil for the empty list, and I think I like the way that mkString is effectively used as a operator. I don't like the lack of space around arithmetic operators though...

Comment: @Antoras - I do like the simpler map rather than yield for colSizes and rows. I didn't like the verbosity of my nested for, but that did reveal the 2D more than `table map {_ map cellSize }`. Maybe I'll find the latter idiomatic soon.

Comment: @Duncan You should default to calling Option on _any_ data returned by Java that might be `null`. Inside your own code, use `Option` and never test for nulls -- if they happen, it is a bug (you forgot to call `Option` on some Java-returned data).